# Get data from Helper or use Model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails app when creating a new Article I need a list of `Users` and `Categories` for some drop-downs so that I can choose both a category and an author for the Article.

Currently I do this in the controller:

```
def new
  @article = Article.new
  @categories = Category.order('title asc').collect { |t| [t.title, t.id] }
  @users = User.order('email asc').collect { |t| [t.email, t.id] }
end
```

And then in the view:

```
<%= f.select :category_id, options_for_select(@categories), :prompt => '-- Please Select --', :required => true %>
```

But according to RubyDocs this is bad practice, and it's not very DRY as I then have to do this for the edit method too. To prevent this, I have two possible alternatives I can think of:

1.) Use a helper like this:

```
def users_for_select
  User.order('email asc').collect { |t| [t.email, t.id] }
end

def categories_for_select
  Category.order('title asc').collect { |t| [t.title, t.id] }
end
```

And then in the view:

```
<%= f.select :category_id, options_for_select(categories_for_select), :prompt => '-- Please Select --', :required => true %>
```

2.) Move it to a Model:

```
def self.categories_for_select
  Category.order('title asc').collect { |t| [t.title, t.id] }
end

def self.users_for_select
  User.order('email asc').collect { |t| [t.email, t.id] }
end
```

And then in the controller do this:

```
def new
  @article = Article.new
  @categories = Category.categories_for_select
  @users = User.users_for_select
end
```

Option 1 feels cleaner as it removes the code from the controller, but I was under the impression that option 2 would be better as it uses a Model for data (as intended) and the controller is still sending the data (again as intended) but more DRY.

I feel their is a sometimes some overlap between Helpers and Models for getting data.

Comment: ..and yet another option - as a kind of in-between of the two - is the decorator pattern - https://github.com/drapergem/draper. The logic is too view-focused to be in your model. Having said that, in the past I've simply used the helper method you described.

Comment: Option 1 is much better than Option 2, Not only DRY, but Model class should respect SRP as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with (1) your helper method for now. It's simple and straightforward. As I said in the comments, you could use a decorator around your model (using [draper](https://github.com/drapergem/draper) for e.g.) to add what I'd consider quite view-specific logic if you are tempted towards option (2).

One note on your helper methods - use [`pluck`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck) instead of `collect` so you don't select columns or instantiate a bunch of objects you don't need.

Also, [`order` defaults to `asc`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/order), so you can shorten the whole thing to:

```
def users_for_select
  User.order(:email).pluck(:email, :id)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a helper method for this:

```
# in a helper
def category_options_for_select
  options_for_select(Category.order(:title).pluck(:title, :id))
end

# in the view
<%= f.select :category_id, category_options_for_select, prompt: '-- Please Select --', required: true %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll personally go with Option 1.

Sure, you could put that in your model. You'll find sooner than later that that would be a great way to bloat up the model. Then you might thinking about using concerns to hide the bloat. And the messy trend continues.

Here's why I think option 1 is better. Even though you aren't creating a separate class to handle formatting, you're still abstracting functionality into a smaller segment which is easier to scale. Plus of course, composition beats inheritance.

This [awesome post](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/) by Bryany gives great options on refractoring fat models.

As @damien already pointed out in his answers you'll want to use ActiveRecord's `pluck` instead of ruby's `collect`. `Pluck` queries the db so that it returns only the objects you need.